# How to make automatic default on question tab when viewing your own profile?

Tags: discussion

There seems to have been a change on SO, now I get a Summary tab shown by default when I visit my profile page - I'd like instead my own view of my profile page to start with Questions tab. Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but then you'd be foiling the SE Devs' plans for world domination.

Comment: Hehe :) Ok, I'll stay put then :) Cheers, @RobertHarvey !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround:

bookmark your user profile while the question tab is active (there is then a `?tab=questions` at the end of the link to your profile). See your questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277826/sdaau?tab=questions)

Then just use your bookmark to access your profile.

Comment: Thanks for that @stema - looks like an acceptable workaround... Cheers!